# Error de Java al instalar Minecraft

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo problemas instalando Minecraft. El error al estar relacionado con Java creo propio realizar la pregunta aquí.

El error es el siguiente:

> Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime
> Environment'

Posteriormente el error es el siguiente:

> Error: could not find java.dll

Y el último error es:

> Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

He probado a reinstalar Java y el propio videojuego pero nada.

Comment: Revisa las variables de entorno.

Comment: Lo siento. Probablemente no podamos ayudarte con esa clase de problemas, menos si no podemos reproducirlo. Si usaste el instalador oficial no deberías tener problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya hay un [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key) en ingles de un problema muy similar, básicamente lo que esta pasando es que quedaron residuos de una version anterior en tu computador.

- elimina los archivos `java.exe`, `javaw.exe` y `javaws.exe`, revisa en las carpetas `Windows\System32` o `Windows\SysWOW64` (en caso que de sistemas x64). Si no encotraste nada ahi,  revisa tambien `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`.
- elimina la carpeta de oracle en `C:\ProgramData\Oracle` (generalmente es esta ubicación)

si ninguna de estos caso resuelve tu problema, ve a la configuración de variables de entorno, y en `PATH` encontraras algo como esto `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`, asegúrate de sea la dirección correcta.

[image: java path direction]

si aun no logras solucionar el problema dale un vistazo al [post original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key)

Comment: Siento la tardanza. Tu solución es la correcta.